# Spaces in column names in Data bricks spark sql - back tick not worked

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a sql query that has a space in the column name in a table that I am querying in Databricks using spark sql. I tried using back tick, double quotes but nothing worked. I need to write the output of this query to the delta lake.

```
Select Table1.`Client Id`, Name, Address from Table1 left join
Table2 on Table1.`Client Id`=Table2.`Client Id`
```

It was giving the error message below. DELTA_INVALID_CHARACTERS_IN_COLUMN_NAMES. Found invalid characters among ' ,;{}()\n\t=' in the column names of your schema. Please use other characters and try again.

How to resolve this? Thanks.

Please advise.

Comment: Backticks should work so when you say "nothing worked" what does that actually mean? Do you get an error and, if so, what's the error message? Obviously, the easiest solution to this is not to use column names with spaces in them :)

Comment: Hi @NickW, I updated the question below. It was giving the error as mentioned above. I want to write the output of the query to the delta lake

Comment: @sparc Can you use [`DESCRIBE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-describe-table) to check the names of *all* the columns in the table?

Comment: Also, is it just that single statement in your question that you are running? When you say "I want to write the output of the query to the delta lake" does that mean this statement is part of a larger piece of code? If that's the case then please update your question with the full code/context

Comment: @NickW, I have updated the question above. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @sparc Note that \t represents a tab character, etc.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I have not used \t, but tried with back tick, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach using PySpark:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT Table1.`Client Id` as `Client_Id`, Name, Address \
                FROM Table1 \
                LEFT JOIN Table2 \
                ON Table1.`Client Id`=Table2.`Client Id`")
```

```
Client_Id   Name    Address
1   dilip   123 Main St
2   dheeraj 456 Second St
3   siri    789 Third St
```

Next, you can rename the column like below:

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed("Client Id", "Client_Id")
```

I have written the output of the query to the delta lake:

```
df.write.format("delta").save("/FileStore/tables/tblog22")
df.display()
```

```
Client_Id   Name    Address
1   dilip   123 Main St
2   dheeraj 456 Second St
3   siri    789 Third St
```